# Concatenate SQL table rows with conditions in single text

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a `SQL` table like this

```
col1     col2      col3
1         0         1
1         1         1
0         1         1
1         0         0
0         0         0
```

I am expecting output as like this

```
col1     col2      col3     NewCol
1         0         1        SL,PL
1         1         1        SL,EL,PL
0         1         1        EL,PL
1         0         0        SL
0         0         0        NULL
```

The condition for this is `if col1>0` then `SL` `else ' '`,  `if col2>0` `EL` `else ' '`, `if col3>0 PL` `else ' '`

I tried to use [Concatenate many rows into a single text string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string) but didn't able to achieve the desired result properly

I have tried It is working fine with a message

> Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

```
WITH CTE AS (
   SELECT col1, col2, col3,
          CASE WHEN col1 > 0 THEN 'SL,' ELSE '' END +
          CASE WHEN col2 > 0 THEN 'EL,' ELSE '' END +
         CASE WHEN col3 > 0 THEN 'PL,' ELSE '' END AS NewCol
   FROM   Employee
)
SELECT col1, col2, col3,
       substring(NewCol, 1, len(NewCol) - 1) AS NewCol
FROM   CTE
```

But again my last condition is not matching if all columns is 0 then I have to show `NULL` as per desired output.

Find the attach fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2bd6a/1

Comment: So... where is your question?

Comment: @cybermonkey I changed my question

Comment: There is still no question being asked here. Please add more details, and add a question. The question you linked to has multiple answers, please share which one of those answers you used in your own sql statement and include the errors, if any.

Comment: @jpw Many columns like `ID,EmpId,Department`

Comment: BTW, is NewCol your new column in table ?In that case it is very wrong to store such value.If it is your output that you want to display then no need of such computed column,you can do so such manipulation with the help of your class property ,thus avoiding such complicated query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue with your code example is that when all columns are 0 then the length is 0 and the substring function will throw an error.

Use `nullif` to fix it: `substring(NewCol, 1, len(nullif(NewCol,'')) - 1) AS NewCol`

Answer (score 2):

You could also change to appending the delimiter on the front and use [`STUFF`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx).

`STUFF('',1,1,'')` will return `NULL` rather than an error.

```
WITH 
Employee(col1, col2, col3) AS (
SELECT 1,1,1 UNION ALL
SELECT 0,0,0
),
CTE AS (
   SELECT col1, col2, col3,
          CASE WHEN col1 > 0 THEN ',SL' ELSE '' END +
          CASE WHEN col2 > 0 THEN ',EL' ELSE '' END +
          CASE WHEN col3 > 0 THEN ',PL' ELSE '' END AS NewCol
   FROM   Employee
)
SELECT col1,
       col2,
       col3,
       STUFF(NewCol, 1, 1, '')
FROM   CTE
```

Returns

```
+------+------+------+------------------+
| col1 | col2 | col3 | (No column name) |
+------+------+------+------------------+
|    1 |    1 |    1 | SL,EL,PL         |
|    0 |    0 |    0 | NULL             |
+------+------+------+------------------+
```

Comment: This also worked. But I have never used STUFF. Thanks for sharing :)

Comment: @SabyasachiMishra - Why "But"? Is it a negative to use something new?

Comment: Ahh maybe you misunderstood my words. I told I have never used as I have never heard of it.

Comment: @SabyasachiMishra - So you probably didn't want the word "but" there. [used to introduce a phrase or clause contrasting with what has already been mentioned.](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1DSGP_enGB502GB502&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=define:but) - It reads as though "It Works" (positive) then "but" would usually introduce a negative.

Comment: @MartinSmith: super liked your answer!!

Answer (score 1):

You have to check with [NULLIF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms177562.aspx) to do this trick

Two ways

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3,
    nullif(CASE WHEN col1  = 1 THEN 'SL,' ELSE '' END +
           CASE WHEN col2  = 1 THEN 'EL,' ELSE '' END +
           CASE WHEN col3  = 1 THEN 'PL,' ELSE '' END,'') AS NewCol 
FROM Employee
```

OR

```
SELECT 
    col1,
    col2,
    col3,
    substring(nullif(NewCol,''), 1, len(NewCol) - 1) AS NewCol
FROM  
    CTE
```